# Config vite to share my component between websites

Tags: svelte, vite

I made a web-app with Svelte and Vite and I added a myLoader.js :

```
export default function myLoader (loaderParams) {
  const app = new App({
    target: loaderParams.container
  })
  }
```

External sites should be able to call myLoader to choose the container where render my component.

My index.html calls main.js who use myLoader to render the app on my site. But myLoader is not present in built files.
How can I keep myLoader in the built files without tree-shaking, code-splitting, renaming and let other sites call it.

Thanks you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

For a library, you should not use an HTML file as entry point.

Configure [`build.lib`](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-lib) to point to a JS file that contains the function export.

I would not recommend trying to serve a library from a regular application. Publish a package instead.